# why it is showing error "Cannot read property 'have' of undefined"?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test my component using `enzyme`.Could you please tell me why I am getting error  **"Cannot read property 'have' of undefined
"**
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/oq7kwzrnj5

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";

import Counter from "./Counter";

describe("counter", () => {
  it("test truty", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Counter />);
    expect(wrapper.find("p")).to.have.length(1);
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: What testing framework do you use?

Comment: Ah its jest,  didn't saw the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use jest the line should look like this:

```
expect(wrapper.find("p").length).toBe(1);
```

or

```
expect(wrapper.find('p').exists()).toBe(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

In code demo you are using **enzyme 3.x**, and in that version **have** is no longer available.

Try with **2.x.** version, or change your expected clause for **3.x** in something like:

```
expect(wrapper.find("p")).toHaveLength(1);
```

Reference: [Enzyme migration guide from 2 to 3](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/migration-from-2-to-3.md)